# Rename multiple files named the same thing throughout a project

Tags: git, shell, ksh

Linux/Bash, I have a directory with many directories inside of it. the inside directories occasionally have the same name of FOO. I want to rename every occurrence of FOO to BAR.

Alternatively, just make git think BAR every time it ever heard FOO. I want the files to stay in their place.

Also, not sure a basic rebase will work to scrub FOO out, due to FOOs being introduced many times.

I have tried:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for oldfile in $(find . -name FOO*)
do
   newfile="BAR"
   mv "$oldfile" "$newfile"
done
```

edit: have also tried: find . -name foo -type d -execdir mv {} bar \;

but i get

find: `./w08/foo': No such file or directory

Comment: `find . -name FOO* -exec mv {} BAR \;`

Comment: @devnull thank you so much, used this and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find with `-execdir`:

```
find . -name "FOO*" -execdir mv '{}' bar \;
```